# updating chrome on Ubuntu 16.10

Tags: google-chrome, 16.10

When I installed chrome on Ubuntu 16.04 an entry in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome is made so it can be updated with sudo apt update. However, when I installed chrome on 16.10 no such entry is created.
Is this because 16.10 is new and google need to update chrome to add the entry or is it a problem on my part?

Comment: It might have been disabled during the upgrade. See the application *Software & Updates* to re-enable them.

Comment: It's *Software Properties* from 16.04 on.

Comment: @grooveplex there nothing there, there should be an enter under the other software tab for chrome but there is nothing. And  I did a fresh install of 16.10 I did not upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

SEE:  https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=660145

AND:  https://github.com/keybase/client/commit/7894c1f57f3ca5ecb3b5fc87e4496769103b7fd4

for possible *** WORK-AROUNDS *** till fixed by upstream.